# Incompatible pointer types assigning to "UITextField" from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextfield, uilabel

I am trying to get the value of a label in productdetailview object and write it on a text field that is located on the edit product object. Could anyone please let me know what the issue is?

Thank you.

Edit:More code added below to solve the label to text field issue.

product.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Product : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *product_id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *model;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *sku;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *quantity;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *imageUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *price;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *weight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *length;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *width;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *height;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *status;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *date_added;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *viewed;


#pragma mark -

#pragma mark Class Methods

-(id) initWithName: (NSString*)pName andProductDescription: (NSString *)pDesc andProductId: (NSString *)pId andModelNumber: (NSString*)mNumber andStoreKeepingUnit:(NSString*)storeKu andProductQuantity:(NSString*)pQuantity andProductImage:(NSURL*)pImage andProductPrice:(NSString*)pPrice andWeight:(NSString*)pWeight  andLength:(NSString*)pLength andWidth:(NSString*)pWidth andHeight:(NSString*)pHeight andProductStatus:(NSString*)pStatus andDateAdded:(NSString*)pDate andProductViewed:(NSString*)pViewed;

@end
```

product.m

```
#import "Product.h"

@implementation Product

@synthesize product_id, date_added, height, weight, width, length, sku, status, imageUrl, model, price, quantity, viewed, name, description;



-(id) initWithName: (NSString*)pName andProductDescription: (NSString *)pDesc andProductId: (NSString *)pId andModelNumber: (NSString*)mNumber andStoreKeepingUnit:(NSString*)storeKu andProductQuantity:(NSString*)pQuantity andProductImage:(NSURL*)pImage andProductPrice:(NSString*)pPrice andWeight:(NSString*)pWeight  andLength:(NSString*)pLength andWidth:(NSString*)pWidth andHeight:(NSString*)pHeight andProductStatus:(NSString*)pStatus andDateAdded:(NSString*)pDate andProductViewed:(NSString*)pViewed
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)

    {
        name=pName;
        description=pDesc;
        product_id= pId;
        model=mNumber;
        sku=storeKu;
        quantity=pQuantity;
        imageUrl=pImage;
        price=pPrice;
        weight=pWeight;
        length=pLength;
        width=pWidth;
        height=pHeight;
        status=pStatus;
        date_added=pDate;
        viewed=pViewed;

    }
    return self;

}
@end
```

//
//  ProductDetailViewController.h

//

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Product.h"
#import "ProductEditViewController.h"
@interface ProductDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductNameLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *ProductDescLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductIdLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductImageUrl;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductModelLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductSkuLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductQuantLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductPriceLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductWeightLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductLenghtLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductWidthLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductHeightLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductStatusLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductDateAddedLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductViewedLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *productDetailImage;

@property(nonatomic, strong) ProductDetailViewController *productEdit;

@property(nonatomic, strong) Product * currentProduct;


#pragma mark -

#pragma mark Methods

-(void)getProduct:(id)productObject;

-(void)setProductLabels;
@end
```

//
//  ProductDetailViewController.m

```
#import "ProductDetailViewController.h"
#import "ProductEditViewController.h"

@interface ProductDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductDetailViewController
@synthesize ProductNameLabel, ProductDescLabel, ProductIdLabel, ProductModelLabel, ProductSkuLabel, ProductQuantLabel, ProductImageUrl, ProductPriceLabel, ProductWeightLabel, ProductLenghtLabel, ProductWidthLabel, ProductHeightLabel, ProductStatusLabel, ProductDateAddedLabel, ProductViewedLabel, productEdit;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     [self setProductLabels];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
#pragma mark-
#pragma mark Methods

-(void)getProduct:(id)productObject{

    _currentProduct = productObject;

}
-(void)setProductLabels{


    ProductNameLabel.text = _currentProduct.name;
    ProductDescLabel.text = _currentProduct.description;
    ProductIdLabel.text = _currentProduct.product_id;
   ProductModelLabel.text = _currentProduct.model;
    ProductSkuLabel.text = _currentProduct.sku;
    ProductQuantLabel.text = _currentProduct.quantity;
       ProductPriceLabel.text = _currentProduct.price;
     ProductWeightLabel.text = _currentProduct.weight;
     ProductLenghtLabel.text = _currentProduct.length;
     ProductWidthLabel.text = _currentProduct.width;
     ProductHeightLabel.text = _currentProduct.height;
     ProductStatusLabel.text = _currentProduct.status;
     ProductDateAddedLabel.text = _currentProduct.date_added;
    ProductViewedLabel.text = _currentProduct.viewed;
}

-(void) productEdit:(UILabel *) productNameLabel {
    if (productNameLabel.tag == 1)
    {
        productEdit.ProductNameLabel.text = ProductNameLabel.text;
    }

}


@end

//
```

ProductsViewController.h

```
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ProductsViewController : UITableViewController
//nsmutable array becuase it changes
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *jsonProductArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *productsArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *productImage;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods


-(void) retrieveProductData;



@end

//
```

ProductsViewController.m

```
//


#import "ProductsViewController.h"
#import "Product.h"
#import "ProductDetailViewController.h"
#define getDataURL @"http://gkhns-macbook-pro.local/gj-4.php"
@interface ProductsViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductsViewController
@synthesize jsonProductArray, productsArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

  //refresh
    [self retrieveProductData];
    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh"] ;
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshProductView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl=refresh;


    self.title = @"PRODUCTS";

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return productsArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"productCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"productCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    //create product image

    Product *productObject;
    productObject = [productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSData *imageData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_productImage];
    UIImage *imageLoad = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
  cell.textLabel.text=productObject.name;
    //load product image
    cell.imageView.image=imageLoad;

    //accessory

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}



/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


#pragma mark - Navigation

//In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushProductDetailView"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        Product* object = [productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [[segue destinationViewController] getProduct:object];





    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Class Methods

-(void) retrieveProductData{

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    jsonProductArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //products array

    productsArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //loop through the jason array

    for (int i=0; i<jsonProductArray.count; i++)

    {
        //create the product object

         NSString *pName  = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *pId  = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"product_id"];
        NSString *pDesc   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
        NSString *mNumber   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"model"];
        NSString *storeKu   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sku"];
        NSString *pQuantity   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"quantity"];

        //product image url
        NSURL *pImage  = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i ] objectForKey:@"image"];
        NSString *pPrice   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"price"];
        NSString *pWeight   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"weight"];
        NSString *pLength   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"length"];
        NSString *pWidth   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"width"];
        NSString *pHeight   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"height"];
        NSString *pStatus   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"status"];
        NSString *pDate   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"date_added"];
        NSString *pViewed   = [[jsonProductArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"viewed"];
        //add product to products array

        [productsArray addObject:[[Product alloc]initWithName: (NSString*)pName andProductDescription: (NSString *)pDesc andProductId: (NSString *)pId andModelNumber: (NSString*)mNumber andStoreKeepingUnit:(NSString*)storeKu andProductQuantity:(NSString*)pQuantity andProductImage:(NSURL*)pImage andProductPrice:(NSString*)pPrice andWeight:(NSString*)pWeight  andLength:(NSString*)pLength andWidth:(NSString*)pWidth andHeight:(NSString*)pHeight andProductStatus:(NSString*)pStatus andDateAdded:(NSString*)pDate andProductViewed:(NSString*)pViewed]];
    }

    //reload the view

    [self.tableView reloadData];


}

//refresh products (pull to refresh)
-(void) refreshProductView:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshProducts{
    refreshProducts.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Updating products..."];
    NSLog(@"Refreshing products");
    [self retrieveProductData];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:m a"];
    NSString *lastUpdatedProduct = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated on %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date] ]];

                                    refreshProducts.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:lastUpdatedProduct];
                                    [refreshProducts endRefreshing];
}



@end
```

//
//  ProductEditViewController.h

//

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ProductEditViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ProductNameEditField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ProductNameEdit;

@end
```

ProductEditViewController.m

```
#import "ProductEditViewController.h"

@interface ProductEditViewController ()

@end

@implementation ProductEditViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ProductNameEditField isn't an NSString, so that's where the problem is.

Try this:

```
productEdit.ProductNameEditField.text = productLabel.text;
```

Comment: I have done this but the text field is now empty. I cannot see the label value on the text field.

Comment: Are you sure the label isn't empty first if you say the text field is now empty?

Comment: Label is not empty first. I can see the label and when I click on edit which takes me to productedit object, I cannot see the labels text inside the text field.

Comment: Try changing your property(ies) from weak to strong

Comment: I have also changed the properties from weak to strong. The end result is the same

Comment: Please post more of your code in original question to see if I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `ProductNameField` (which is a `UITextField`) to `productLabel.text` (which is `NSString`) and you can't do that because they're not the same type of object.

You probably want:

```
productEdit.ProductNameEditField.text = productLabel.text;
```